# Prove that there is a unique topology is the coarsest containing topologies $T_\alpha$

Tags: general-topology

$\{T_\alpha\}$ is a family of topologies on $X$. Prove that there is a unique
coarsest topology containing topologies $T_\alpha$ and a unique finest topology contained in all topologies $T_\alpha$.

Comment: Using common terminology, the statement should read “prove that there is a unique topology, the coarsest, containing all topologies $T_a$ and a unique topology, the finest, contained in all topologies $T_a$”.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I’m pretty sure that the OP used a general bilingual dictionary to translate the terms that came out as *rude* and *thin*; in some non-mathematical contexts these are synonyms of the desired *coarse* and *fine*.

Comment: @lily Are you familiar with the fact that for **every** subset $\mathcal V\subseteq\wp(X)$ there exist a smallest topology that contains $\mathcal V$ (the topology generated by $\mathcal V$)? So also for $\mathcal V:=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}T_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Ok. Then the finest topology contained in all topologies is the union and the intersection is the coarsest topology? @drhab

Comment: @lily I am afraid not. An intersection of topologies on the same set $X$ is a topology itself. To find the coarsest topology that contains every $T_{\alpha}$ you must take the intersection of all topologies that contain $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}T_{\alpha}$. The finest topology contained in every $T_{\alpha}$ is intersection $\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}T_{\alpha}$. As said: both are topologies since they are both an intersection of topologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the second part:

Let $\tau$ denote a topology such that it is contained in every $T_{\alpha}$.

So denoting the index set by $A$ we have:$$\tau\subseteq\bigcap_{\alpha\in A} T_{\alpha}\tag1$$

Fortunately it can be shown that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in A} T_{\alpha}$ is a topology itself (try to prove that yourself) and $(1)$ tells us that any topology that is contained in every $T_{\alpha}$ is coarser (i.e. has no more elements).

This allows us to conclude that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in A} T_{\alpha}$ is the finest topology that is contained in every $T_{\alpha}$.

---

On the first part.

As said in the comments the intersection of a collection of topologies on $X$ is a topology itself.

If $\mathcal V\subseteq\wp(X)$ then we can take the collection of all topologies that contain $\mathcal V\subseteq\wp(X)$ and then take the intersection of these topologies.  Denoting this intersection by $\tau_{\mathcal V}$ we observe that:

- $\tau_{\mathcal V}$ is a topology.
- $\mathcal V\subseteq\tau_{\mathcal V}$
- If $\rho$ is a topology with $\mathcal V\subseteq\rho$ then  $\tau_{\mathcal V}\subseteq\rho$

This together tells us that $\tau_{\mathcal V}$ is the coarsest topology that contains $\mathcal V$.

You are searching for the coarsest topology that contains every $T_{\alpha}$ or equivalently for the coarsest topology that contains $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}T_{\alpha}$, so you can apply this.